# kafka + ReplicaFetcherThread & Error for partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka cluster with 11 brokers on Linux machines

brokers IDS are

```
1001
1002
.
.
.
1011
```

we have topics as  - my_first_car , with `300 partitions` , and this topic configured with replication `factor = 3`

we notice from server.log the following `ERRORS`  ( from the first broker - 1001 )

```
[2022-03-02 07:15:52,450] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1005], Error for partition [my_first_car1,57] to broker 1005:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)


[2022-03-02 07:15:52,450] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1005], Error for partition [my_first_car2,37] to broker 1005:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

**what we can learn from ERRORS above?**

`server.log` on all Kafka's is filled with that `ERRORS`

is that `ERROR` could be related to network problem or else?

need to mention that all `kafka` services are up ,

and we set the correct Kafka heap size memory

Other similar posts:

https://www.saoniuhuo.com/question/detail-1973429.html?sort=new

[Issue with Kafka Broker - UnknownServerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665081/issue-with-kafka-broker-unknownserverexception)

[Is it possible to add partitions to an existing topic in Kafka 0.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677871/is-it-possible-to-add-partitions-to-an-existing-topic-in-kafka-0-8-2/58293572#58293572)

[Execute to alter kafka topic partition number, occurred UnknownServerException with other topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387424/execute-to-alter-kafka-topic-partition-number-occurred-unknownserverexception-w)

[Reproducing UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514923/reproducing-unknowntopicorpartitionexception-this-server-does-not-host-this-top)

https://russianblogs.com/article/76231330936/

https://www.orchome.com/237

https://www.orchome.com/496

as I know - UnknownTopicOrPartitionException

Literally: topic or partition does not exist.
For example: topic has a total of 3 partitions, p0, p1, p2, and if you specify to write data to p3, this exception will be reported

but in my case the topics partitions are exists